# DiffUtil , Add a ListListener to receive updates when the current List changes

Tags: android, listener

I need a listener to be notified by diffutil every time a new list is created.

I added a listener to diffutil(differ.addListListener) but it is only called once.

When I send the first 20 items to diffutil it works fine but does not work next time.

```
val differCallback=object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PlantItem>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PlantItem, newItem: PlantItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PlantItem, newItem: PlantItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem)
    }
}
val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)

differ.addListListener { previousList, currentList ->
    Log.i(TAG,"list Size "+currentList.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better results, try modifying the areContentsTheSame() method. In this method you should check for equality of each and every content between newItem and oldItem rather than the id (ids will be checked in areItemsTheSame() method).

Comment: I changed the areContentsTheSame () method, but the result did not change and the listener is only called for the first time

Comment: Actually I use Java for Android Development. Here in Java we create a final object of DiffUtil.ItemCallback and pass this object in the super constructor of ListAdapter. This diffUtil callback then manages whenever there is any change in the list and add more animations. Maybe this could help-  https://www.raywenderlich.com/21954410-speed-up-your-android-recyclerview-using-diffutil